# Get rid content between <!-- and // -->

Tags: java, regex, xhtml

I have a text file which is the result of parsed HTML into plain text file. I need to get rid of which is something like XHTML comment like the following shows:

```
<!--
if (!document.phpAds_used)
 document.phpAds_used = ',';
 phpAds_random = new String
 (Math.random()); phpAds_random =
 phpAds_random.substring(2,11);
 document.write ("<" + "script
 language='JavaScript'
 type='text/javascript' src='");
 document.write
 ("http://www.writers.net/Openads/adjs.php?n="
 + phpAds_random); document.write ("&what=zone:5&target=_blank");
 document.write ("&exclude=" +
 document.phpAds_used); if
 (document.referrer) document.write
 ("&referer=" +
 escape(document.referrer));
 document.write ("'><" + "/script>");
 // -->
```

How can I get rid of anything between `<!--` and `//-->` using Java?

Comment: Does the file contain another HTML? If so, do you want to keep it or to get rid of (some of) it as well?

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to use the [String.replaceAll()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method.

For example, something like the following code should work:

```
String x = "wow <!-- // --> zip, here's <!-- comment here //--> another one";
x = x.replaceAll("<!--.*?//\\s*-->", "");
System.out.println(x);  // prints out "wow  zip, here's  another one"
```

The `\\s*` matches none or many spaces since your example had a space but your description did not.  The `.*?` makes this a non-greedy match so it will match up to the first `//-->`

If you are running this over and over, you could use the `Pattern` instead and just regenerate the matcher for each block you are processing:

```
Pattern.compile("<!--.*?//\\s*-->").matcher(x).replaceAll("")
```